# How to redirect stderr to stderr or stdout in Ant?

Tags: ant, exec

If I set `output` attribute

```
<exec executable="tidy.exe" output="content2.html">
            <arg line="-clean content.html"/>

        </exec>
```

it takes both `stdout` and `stderr` to a file. I need only `stdout`. How to leave `stderr` in place, i.e. going to console?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the ant Exec Task manual](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html), you must set the attribute "error" to a separate file, otherwise the stderr will appear in the "output"-defined file.

> output - Name of a file to which to write the output. If the error stream is not also redirected to a file or property, it will appear in this output.
>
> error - The file to which the standard error of the command should be redirected.

Comment: I know. But I want to redirect only stdout, leaving stderr intact.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible.

The next question would be, why do want to accomplish that? If it's to see just the error messages, I'd recommend using the error flag to output to a file and use a log viewer like Baretail to monitor it.